# binary-i386/packages file not found, how can I stop APT looking for them?

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade

An upgrade from lucid to precise went horribly wrong and it apparently tried to install part of an i386 arch on an amd64 machine. Too much to manually fix, so refreshed with a precise amd64 dist. Luckily install was on separate partition and all config and `/home` were saved so I could restore it and nothing lost.

Except for this issue all working fine for the past month, including new installs and updates.

But from `apt-get update` we still have:

```
/var/cache/apt-build/repository/dists/apt-build/main/binary-i386/Packages File not found.
No partials found.
```

In all `/etc/apt` files the only binary-i386 entries are already commented out.

All the `apt-get` cleaning variations have been tried (I think...).

What is flagging apt-get to look for these files?

Answer (score 2):

As written [elsewhere](http://www.ubuntuask.com/q/answers-ubuntu-64-bit-failed-to-fetch-file-binary-i386-packages-error-while-updat-394653.html), you may edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt-build.list` to contain:

```
deb [arch=amd64] file:/var/cache/apt-build/repository apt-build main
```

This is due to the fact that now multi-arch is default on amd64, but apt-build only generates the amd64 repo (I do not know whether apt-build can build multi-arch or cross-compile). I tried to `apt-get install apt-build:i386` as it may also solve the problem, but there were broken dependencies, so that venue may or may not be viable.

By the way, this is also a problem in Debian 7.0.

Answer (score 2):

OP's solution edited out of the question:

> Nothing found anywhere, so after reading all the man pages and how-to's I looked for something referencing main or dist, instead of i386. In `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt-build.list` I found:
>
> ```
> deb file:/var/cache/apt-build/respository apt-build main
> ```
>
> and could not find any reason that should be there. As that was the only entry, I deleted that file. Problem is now solved.